# Execution failed for task ':compileJava'

Tags: java, gradle, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle, spring-cloud

I am trying to build a Spring cloud application that provides details of a Customer and the order history he/she has made in the past via gradle. When I am executing the build and clean task, I am unable to obtain the target jar file because of this error.

Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

This is the message shown in the ExceptionStackTrace of the error log.

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\gradle\gradle-3.4.1'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
```

Below is my build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'yBayApplication'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-turbine:1.2.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:1.2.3.RELEASE')  
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

I have checked the Java version which gradle uses and it points to the right directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121` and I have also included the `gradle.properties` file in the project to be double sure that it fetches only the `Java_home` properties

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

I had also changed the `eclipse.ini` file by adding the following lines.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe
```

Still I find that the gradle build is failing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Error log has following errors
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\gradle\gradle-3.4.1'.
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
 at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
 .....

Comment: Since it's windows, and since you have spaces on the path to java executables: did you try to enclose the path to the JDK (for gradle) into ""?
=> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"`

Comment: Spring Cloud Camden.SR6 is the first version to support spring boot 1.5.x

Comment: I am unable to import the maven dependencies from build.gradle. I noticed that the errors were mainly appearing because of the class files. 
:clean
:compileJavaC:\Users\Adithya\workspace\yBayApplication\src\main\java\com\aspiretraining\model\Order.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import javax.persistence.Entity;
             
  location: package javax.persistence
ApplicationServer.java:13: error: package org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server does not exist
symbol: class EnableEurekaServer
error: package org.springframework.data.repository does not exist

Comment: @cyberbrain changing the version worked. :)
But i am still having trouble in importing spring-boot-starter-actuator and spring-cloud-starter for hystrix and hystrix dashboard.

Comment: @cyberbrain 

> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:.
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.pom      
      https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator//spring-boot-starter-actuator-.jar
> Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard
> Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:.

Comment: @spencergibb i think that approach worked too. I am not exactly sure though since I followed both steps from you and cyberbrain at the same time.